# How to fix "Debug Error!, Stack around the variable 'x' was corrupted"?

Tags: c, if-statement, char

I am really new to C-language and was testing a simple if-statement program which, from your age and gender tells one answer from 4 different outcomes.

Which goes something like this:
If you are under the age of 55 and are male, it will print:
"You are a man at his best age!"

But I come across a error code which says: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'miesVaiNainen' was corrupted.

I myself, think it might have something to do with: `if (manOrFemale == "f" && age <= 55)`

How can I fix this issue so the error wont come across?

I've tried to look for help in stackoverflow and tried to change the code a lot.

```
    int age;
    char manOrFemale;

    printf("Are you a man or a female(m/f)");
    scanf("%s", &manOrFemale);

    printf("Input age:");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    if (manOrFemale == "f" && age <= 55)
    {
        printf("\nYou are a lady at her best!");
    } else if (manOrFemale == "f" && age >= 56)
    {
        printf("\nYou look young for your age!");
    }


    if (manOrFemale == "m" && age <= 55)
    {
        printf("\nYou are a man at his best age!");
    } else if (manOrFemale == "m" && age >= 56)
    {
        printf("\nYou are a wise man!");
    } else {
        printf("There has been an error in the program!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now you are using `%s` specifier to read `char`.
you need to use `%c` specifier to read `char`, `%s` is for `char *`.

```
  scanf(" %c", &manOrFemale);
```

And

you need to use single quotes to compare `chars`. As of now you are comparing
`char` with pointer.

```
if (manOrFemale == 'f'; && age <= 55)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a *very* large problem:

```
scanf("%s", &manOrFemale);
```

The variable `manOrFemale` is a single character. The format `"%s"` is to read null-terminated byte strings.

A string of only a single character needs space for *two* characters, to fit the null-terminator. Since you don't have space for the terminator, the `scanf` function will write into memory you don't own, clobbering the stack (where compilers usually store local variables) leading to the error you get.

If you want to read a single character, then use the `"%c"` format, as in

```
scanf(" %c", &manOrFemale);
```

Do note the leading space in the format string, it's needed to ignore possible leading white-space (like newlines from any previous input).

---

Also note that with the comparison `manOrFemale == "f"` you compare the single character in `manOrFemale` with the *string* `"f"`. A literal string in C is really a read-only array of characters, and as any array it decays to a pointer to its first element. So you're not comparing characters, you're comparing a character with a pointer.

Your compiler should have warned you about this.

To solve this you need to compare to a single character instead: `manOrFemale == 'f'`. Note the use of single-quotes instead.

---

Lastly a more stylistic note...

The statements

```
if (manOrFemale == 'f' && age <= 55)
{
    printf("\nYou are a lady at her best!");
} else if (manOrFemale == 'f' && age >= 56)
{
    printf("\nYou look young for your age!");
}
```

could be rewritten as

```
if (manOrFemale == 'f')
{
    if (age <= 55)
        printf("You are a lady at her best!\n");
    else
        printf("You look young for your age!\n");
}
```

One extra thing to note here is that I use *trailing* newline in the output. That's because otherwise there might not be a newline after the program finishes (so the output seems to be intermingled with the command-line prompt), but also because output to `stdout` (where `printf` writes) is by default *line-buffered*. Line-buffering means that output is buffered internally, and not actually written to the terminal until either the buffer is full, *or a newline is written*. If you use leading newlines in your output, then the previous line will be written, not the current line.

Comment: Thank you to you too :)!. I am using CLion by Jetbrain with a student license.